# Merge multiple user ids

Tags: user-management

I have a developer user id that was set up on force.com before my company was set up on Salesforce.com.  I was invited to my company SF, but my email address is already in use - by my other account. So I setup a different userid using an abbreviated email address.  Is there a way to merge my two user ids together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username must be unique and be in the form of an email address, but it doesn't have to be a real email address. I would recommend you log into your developer org and change your login there. I use a naming convention such as user@example.com.de. Once you've freed up your user name, log into your company's org and change your login there. Both accounts can have the same email address.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Now I understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge a user between two different orgs. The *developer* and *production* org (your company org) have nothing to do with each other and are silos except for a sandbox.

What sorts of information are you trying to move? Just the use of the email address as a login/userid at the salesforce login page?

Your email acts as a router into the org from the login page, you may be able to contact Salesforce and have them remove that 'developer' org so you can reuse the email as a login elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Now I understand it better.